# What parameters could be used to test an encryption library

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, encryption, webcrypto-api

I've written an encryption library using Typescript and webcryptoapi. For reporting purposes I need to make some mathematical performance analysis of the protocol.

For demo purposes, I've created a simple HTML page with couple of text boxes and encryption, decryption button as well couple of labels to show auxiliary data helping to encryption and decryption.

However, Webcryptoapi, runs locally inside the browser, thus no api call is made. Hence, I'm kindly asking you what kind of performance test I could apply? So far I measured the durations for key derivation, encryption and decryption. In addition, I estimated a possible data usage. However, because it is one javascript file, I dont have a chance to see big differences in memory usage and so on. If anyone could give me further ideas about what I could test, I would appreciate it so much

Comment: What are you intending to use this for?   What metric are you concerned about/interested in testing?

Comment: It is a location based encryption protocol devised for a master thesis. For the scope of master thesis, it would be tremendous amount of work to do an app with using this library from the ground up. Hence, we just intended to do the library option. You give the location and the message as well as some other information to the library and it outputs the encrypted text. Hence, the supervisor wants to see some performance analysis and he wasnt keen on helping me in terms of giving an insight into what i could test. he just said i wanna see performance anaylsis and numbers.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark any ideas dear Luke?

Comment: Is testing the viability of the algorithm itself in-scope?  It sounds like it would be relatively insecure.